# Why does dynamic content stop evaluating in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I've created a pipeline which extracts from 1300+ tables from various sources. It ran successfully for 800+ runs, however, after awhile the dynamic content for a stored procedure activity stopped evaluating correctly and passed the string literal of the dynamic content instead.

**snippet of the activity input when failing**

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[usp_update_extract_record_success]",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "copy_duration": {
            "value": "@activity('Copy Odbc').output.copyDuration",
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        "data_read": {
            "value": "@coalesce(activity('Copy Odbc').output.dataRead,null)",
            "type": "Int64"
        }
```

**snippet of the activity input when succeeded**

```
{
    "storedProcedureName": "[dbo].[usp_update_extract_record_success]",
    "storedProcedureParameters": {
        "copy_duration": {
            "value": 111,
            "type": "Int64"
        },
        "data_read": {
            "value": 76844376,
            "type": "Int64"
        }
```

**You can see I've added the dynamic content correctly, and not as a string value**

[image: dynamic content]

I've changed the integration runtime from autoresolve to a self hosted integration runtime. I noticed when the failure occurs the integration runtime is recorded as 'Unknown'. So was hoping this may fix the problem.

I also increased the retry attempts for the activity incase it was a transient issue, but it appears to reoccur.

Comment: Any changes recently you have done that might impact your activity or pipeline?

Comment: Can you share the error message in stored procedure activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried the same and got the same error when I have used the wrong dynamic expression.

**To resolve this, make sure you are using correct Dynamic expression without spelling mistakes and case sensitivity with proper hierarchy.**

[image]

If it's taking input as string, make sure you convert it into an Int. with expression like `@int(activity('Copy Odbc').output.copyDuration`

So, it will Fetch the input correctly and process it.

[image]